# SQL server 2008 Express x64 in windows 8.1 fail

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've been download sql server express x64 version in [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22973)

I just install new windows 8.1 x64 vl version and install trial KIS for anti-virus. After i install sql server but it's not working

[image]

and

[image]

i uninstall KIS, SQL server and install avast and sql server again but the same :(.

How to fix that thanks.

Comment: You probably need to use SQL Server Configuration Manager to enable `TCP/IP` connections.  See http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47253/cannot-connect-to-my-local-instance for more info

Comment: Perhaps try using (localhost) as the server name?

Comment: Also, you may want to seriously reconsider using anti-virus on a SQL Server machine (assuming it is only being used for SQL Server and doesn't allow users to surf the web etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to use "SQLExpress" as a server name.  I'm guessing that's the instance name.  Connect to ".\SQLExpress" instead.

Answer (score 0):

1) Enable TCP/IP connections from Configuration Manager as Max has suggested.

or

2) Please try re-installing it by disabling anti-virus and also firewall (if it is on). I guess there may be issues with Ports assigned for SQL Server.